# How to dump MoarVM bytecode

Tags: raku, moarvm

I wonder how I can debug the Moarvm bytecode. Is there a document that describes for instance
howto convert raku to moarvm and howto dump the generated bytecode. If i try to i.e. run:

```
rakudo-m --target=mbc c.p6 
===SORRY!===
Cannot dump this object; no dump method
```

Somewhere I read about a "--dump" switch but that doesnt seem avaiable. I custom compile rakudo/nqp/moarvm from github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` argument to the rakudo compiler requires an `--output=filename` for some of the values. `parse`, `ast`, and `optimize` will all happily output to a console, though.

The `moar` binary is what has the `--dump` flag, but I would perhaps suggest using the debug output from the *spesh* subsystem of moarvm, which is the dynamic bytecode specializer and jit.

You can get at it by setting the environment variable `MVM_SPESH_LOG` to a filename. If the code in question doesn't run often enough to appear in the *spesh log*, you can set `MVM_SPESH_NODELAY` so `moar` will consider routines "hot" much earlier. There will be less information for the optimizer to work with, but if you're after seeing the compilation result only, it should be just fine.